# Unloading exterior, loading interior (viceversa), without loading screens?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm wondering what the wording is for this sort of stuff that most games nowadays are doing, it's where the player loads into these interiors incredibly fluidly with no loading screen behind it. Example below:

https://youtu.be/oIpRHJl-ZE8?t=880

Is there a wording for it, how would I really go about it? I know there's probably chunks here, being unloaded / loaded in, but is there any way of working with the regular Unity terrain and doing this?

There's a few ways of doing this sort of stuff so I thought I'd ask for the better option. I know some like to just teleport the player below the map to make it easy, do please let me know what options I might have for something like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd have everything loaded and different areas held in separated folder like game objects.
As you pass from one environment to another just gameObject.SetActive(false) on one folder and true on another. It's a little wasteful for memory but the interior scenes are fairly simple so not too bad.
If you need a bigger external area, think about building a tile system that loads the area progressively in the background as you move towards it.

Comment: Interesting, I don't believe there'll be any major heavy interiors. It's only the exterior world that will be big. Think of the Harvest Moon games the Wonderful Life one, I guess, in terms of size.

I was thinking of using this with it:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/object-chunks-192830#reviews

To simplify the dev process, it could work with your suggestion too.

Comment: That looks like a good asset. I might have a look at that myself.